# admin-ajax.php returns 0. How do I debug it and fix it?

Tags: ajax, uploads, post-thumbnails

Trying to use `admin-ajax.php` to upload image from front-end form. I'm keep getting `0` with below code I have and not sure how to debug this or where it goes wrong.

I have HTML input file

```
<input type="file" name="wh_image_upload" id="wh_image_upload" multiple="false" />
```

and localized script for AJAX request

```
$img_nonce = wp_create_nonce('image_upload_nonce');
wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_image', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )) );
```

and PHP function

```
function write_here_featured_image_upload() {
    var_dump($_FILES);
    die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_write_here_img_upload', 'write_here_featured_image_upload' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_write_here_img_upload', 'write_here_featured_image_upload' );
```

JS

```
// Featured image upload AJAX
    $("#wh_image_upload").change(function(){
        var userFile    =   new FormData();  
        var fileInput   =   $( "#wh_image_upload" )[0].files[0];
        //console.log(fileInput);

        userFile.append("file", fileInput);
        userFile.append("action", "write_here_img_upload");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
            data: userFile,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
                console.log(errorMessage);
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("Image Uploaded! " + data);
            }
        });
    });
```

I get a AJAX success message with response `0`. `Image Uploaded! 0`

**Update**
I updated my working code.

Comment: If you only want to run ajax on the admin side of things remove the `nopriv` hook - [The Codex says](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)): `This hook is functionally the same as wp_ajax_(action), however it is used to handle AJAX requests on the front-end`

Comment: Updated working code on question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [Enable Debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

WordPress has constants defined in `wp-config.php` where you can print errors to the screen and log them in a separate file located `/wp-content/debug.log`. It looks like this:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

You can  then print your own information to the debug log at specific point and find out exactly where ( or if the function is even getting hit at all ) the function is erroring out:

```
function write_here_featured_image_upload() {
    error_log( 'Made it into the Ajax function safe and sound!' );
    /** ... Rest of your code ... **/
}
```

### Check Dev Tools Console

Almost all browsers in this modern day have [Developer Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Discover_browser_developer_tools) and a [Console](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Your_Browser_to_Diagnose_JavaScript_Errors#Step_3:_Diagnosis) where Javascrpit errors are output to. If you see an error in your Dev Tools console you'll need to fix that first and foremost.

---

As for a possible solution, you have this conditional which is preventing you from running ajax on the front-end of the website:

```
if ( is_admin() ) {
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_write_here_img_upload', 'write_here_featured_image_upload' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_write_here_img_upload', 'write_here_featured_image_upload' );
}
```

The function [`is_admin()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin) tells WordPress to **only** run those actions whenever in the Admin Panel / Dashboard so you would never see anything happen on the front-end of your website. Try removing the conditional and just adding the action as is:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_write_here_img_upload', 'write_here_featured_image_upload' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_write_here_img_upload', 'write_here_featured_image_upload' );
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately removing `is_admin()` does not make any different. I'm still getting `0` for return. I have turned on all three debug mode but don't see any `debug.log` file created. Woking on Localhost might be the issue??

Comment: @Ohsik shouldn't be. What happens if you hit the URL directly? `http://localhost/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=write_here_img_upload&test=true` - you'll have to add a `die( 'here' );` above your nonce check to see if you're even getting into the function.

Comment: I'm getting `-1` on `check_ajax_referer( 'image_upload_nonce', 'security');` by accessing the URL directly

Comment: Yes, it created `debug.log` but it just says `Made it into the Ajax function safe and sound!`. Could please tell me where to go from here?

Comment: @Ohsik From there you debug what the issue is. Maybe dump your `$_POST` and `$_GET` values into the log: `error_log( print_r( $val, 1 ) );`. If I was a betting man I would bet that `$_FILES` is empty and you need to set an encrypttype.

Comment: Yes, $_FILES seems to be empty. means something wrong in JS?

Comment: You need to add an enctype to your form: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4526286/800452

Comment: That's the issue for me cause I'm not actually submitting a form. I make AJAX request on `$("#wh_image_upload").change`. Any idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32080/discussion-between-howdy-mcgee-and-ohsik).

Comment: `action` seems to be pass with `data`. I removed `action: "write_here_img_upload",` in $ajax and added `userFile.append("action", "write_here_img_upload");`

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside admin-ajax.php

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?